# extract and display matching strings with similar pattern

Tags: bash

I have an extremely long line. It contains a lot of strings with a similar patterns like below;

```
t[0-4]_vmdk_[a-z]_anything
```

t followed by a single digit with possible 0-4, and them '_vmdk_', and any long string with possible [a-z], then finally "_" in the end. The rest could be anything.

Ex:

```
asdfasfsa/_asdf**t2_vmdk_abc_**badfad**t3_vmdk_xyz_**asdfasdf**t1_vmdk_efg_**asbafdfb....
```

Please help me to display all such strings. Thank you!

Comment: What's the expected output for the input example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest is probably with `grep`. If the input string comes from the standard output of another command (e.g. `echo`):

```sh
$ str='asdfasfsa/_asdf**t2_vmdk_abc_**badfad**t3_vmdk_xyz_**asdfasdf**t1_vmdk_efg_**asbafdfb....'
$ echo "$str" | grep -o 't[0-4]_vmdk_[a-z]*'
t2_vmdk_abc
t3_vmdk_xyz
t1_vmdk_efg
```

Explanation: the `-o` option prints "*only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line*".

If the input strings are stored in a file:

```sh
$ grep -o 't[0-4]_vmdk_[a-z]*' file.txt
t2_vmdk_abc
t3_vmdk_xyz
t1_vmdk_efg
```

Comment: if OP also wants the `**anything**` part then the ERE could become a bit hardcore

Comment: As far as I understand the question they don't want it. I may be wrong, it is yet not 100% clear what they want because they don't show the expected output for their provided example...

Comment: That is what I wanted to achieve. Thank you!

Comment: @vkky2k So, please edit your question and add your expected output for the example string. This way the question (and my answer) will be complete and maybe helpful for others. And if this answer solves your problem [you know what to do next, do you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Comment: I already edited my original question. and also accepted by checking the mark.

Comment: You edited your original question to show the input but you did not add the **expected output**.